# How to overwrite crosssell template in custom module?

Tags: module, theme, cross-sells

I am trying to display custom information for cross-sell items. I want to overwrite app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml

and use a new template in my module. I've tried a couple of ways to no avail. Here is my code:

in my config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <crosssellAttributes_layout module="CrosssellAttributes">
                <file>crosssellattributes.xml</file>
            </mymodulename_layout>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

and in my layout modulename.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<checkout_cart_crosssell>
    <reference name="checkout.cart.crosssell">
        <block type="napkinstudio_productcrosssell/catalog_product_view_crosssell" name="product.view.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="[templatename]/productcrosssell.phtml" />
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>[templatename]/productcrosssell.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_crosssell>
```

I want it to point to my child theme file, but can't seem to get it right. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your config.xml code

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <crosssellAttributes_layout module="CrosssellAttributes">
                <file>crosssellattributes.xml</file>
            </mymodulename_layout>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

to:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <crosssellAttributes>
                <file>crosssellattributes.xml</file>
            </crosssellAttributes>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

In above code crosssellAttributes is your module group name

Answer (score 0):

At first you config xml looks incorrect, should be something like

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <napkinstudio_productcrosssell>
                <file>crosssellattributes.xml</file>
            </napkinstudio_productcrosssell>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

then you need to create crosssellattributes.xml file withing your design package layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="napkinstudio_productcrosssell/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

and then you need to create a template file within you desing package theme template folder - napkinstudio_productcrosssell/cart/crosssell.phtml